# Print images inside Magnific

Tags: jquery, button, magnific-popup

Is it possible to add a button and be able to print images directly from Magnific?

Comment: I've installed PrintArea plugin which brings up print window but no content is appearing in the preview window. Is there any special way to reference an image in Magnific? I've tried various versions of "mfp-content", "mfp-figure" as well as "mfp-img". Thanks in advance for any assistance. Todd

Comment: Just checking in to see if anyone can give me some pointers :)

Comment: You might try posting one or two of your attempts.